# Why was a build cancelled in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

A YAML build pipeline execution was cancelled in Azure DevOps. No logs are available for download. How do I find out why it was cancelled?

This execution was started automatically by Bitbucket to verify a pull request. I might figure out the reason of cancellation if I review Bitbucket's webhook logs (if Bitbucket has cancelled it), but is there a way to find it out from Azure DevOps?

Knowing what event or user have triggered cancellation is enough.

Comment: I'm also having trouble getting logs for PR pipelines that are cancelled remotely.  The ADO REST api shows that the build was manually deleted.  There's no timeline available for the build and no logs.

Comment: Very annoying that it's not possible to see who has cancelled a build, if it was cancelled manually. And it doesn't matter if comes via BitBucket or ADO...

Answer (score 0):

Any pipelines run started in Azure DevOps should be visible in https://dev.azure.com/YOURORGANIZATION/YOURTEAMPROJECT/_build?view=runs (replace YOURORGANIZATION and YOURTEAMPROJECT with your own). Another way is to check the Agent Pool (but then you'll need to know which Agent Pool was used);

1. Navigate to your organization: https://dev.azure.com/YOURORGANIZATION
2. Click **Organization settings** in the right bottom corner
3. Click **Agent pools** under **Pipelines**
4. Choose the Agent Pool
5. Then you see the jobs that reached an Agent

From either of the two options, you should be able to check the logs or warnings to find out what is wrong.

If it's not there, it never started, and you should check BitBucket.

Comment: There are no logs available for download.

Comment: You say there are no logs available, but is there a job visible in the history of the Agent Pool?